# How to prevent error being displayed in NetSuite?

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I am writing a script to take a value from one field and place it into a list field in NetSuite. I believe the issue is because upon saving the record a value is trying to be set in a list that does not contain that value.

**I want this to fail silently when set within the context of my script, how can I prevent the error message from showing up and allow the record to be created but without that field being populated?**

Scenario - Value is placed into this field, the script tries to map that value to a list value (IT DOES NOT EXIST), the record should still save, but without that data being set - NO ERRORS.

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType UserEventScript
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
 */
define(['N/record', 'N/log'],
/**
 * @param {record} record
 */
function(record) {

    function customer_beforeLoad(scriptContext) {

    }

    function customer_beforeSubmit(scriptContext) {

        //Segment
        setNonIntegrationFieldValue(scriptContext, 'custentity_cus_segmentintegration', 'custentity_cus_segment');
        //Currency
        setNonIntegrationFieldValue(scriptContext, 'custentity_cus_primarycurrencyintegratio', 'currency');
        //Billing Cycle
        setNonIntegrationFieldValue(scriptContext, 'custentity_cus_billingcycleintegration', 'custentity_cus_billingcycle');
        //Type
        setNonIntegrationFieldValue(scriptContext, 'custentity_cus_typeintegration', 'custentity_cus_type');
        //Industry
        setNonIntegrationFieldValue(scriptContext, 'custentity_cus_industryintegration', 'custentity_esc_industry');
        //Sales Rep
        setNonIntegrationFieldValue(scriptContext, 'custentity_cus_salesrepintegration', 'salesrep');
    }

    function customer_afterSubmit(scriptContext) {

    }

    function setNonIntegrationFieldValue(scriptContext, integrationFieldName, actualFieldName){
      try {
        var integrationFieldValue = scriptContext.newRecord.getValue(integrationFieldName);
        if(integrationFieldValue == '' || integrationFieldValue == null){
            scriptContext.newRecord.setValue({
                fieldId: actualFieldName,
                value: ''
            });
        } else {
            scriptContext.newRecord.setText({
                fieldId: actualFieldName,
                text: integrationFieldValue
            });
        }
      } catch(e){
        log.error({
          title: "setNonIntegrationFieldValue() has encountered an error.",
          details: e.message
        });
        //nlapiLogExecution('ERROR','setNonIntegrationFieldValue() has encountered an error.', errText(e));
      }
    }

    return {
        //beforeLoad: customer_beforeLoad,
        beforeSubmit: customer_beforeSubmit,
        //afterSubmit: customer_afterSubmit
    };

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution should not be preventing a message from showing up, instead, it should be preventing setting of the value when it's not a valid value. You can try firstly get the array of all valid options in that list, secondly check if the value you want to use is contained in the array, if yes then set the value.

To be specific:

```
var actualField = scriptContext.form.getField(actualFieldName);
var options = actualField.getSelectOptions();
var integrationFieldValue = scriptContext.newRecord.getValue(integrationFieldName);
if (options.indexOf(integrationFieldValue) > -1) {
scriptContext.newRecord.setText({
                fieldId: actualFieldName,
                text: integrationFieldValue
            });
}
```

For more details for the function getSelectOptions, please refer to Netsuite Help center (search Field.getSelectOptions)

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap ANY AND ALL netsuite logic with a try catch. We have over 614,00 LOC in netsuite and this works 100%:

```
try {
   // your code here
} catch (e) {
   // this ternary operator will catch all the ns errors. you can fail silently here
   var error = e.details || e.message || e.toString();
   throw error;
}
```